# How do I write $2(2^k+1) - 1$ as $(2 \cdot 2^k + 1)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

How do I write $2(2^k+1) - 1$ as $(2 \cdot 2^k + 1)$?

Mathematically, it is equivalent. But I need to the former form into the latter form for step 2 of inductive step for mathematical induction problem.

Comment: $2(2^k+1)=2\cdot 2^k+2\cdot 1=2\cdot2^k+2$.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your actual induction problem--the above is simply in need of a basic algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distributing out the $2$ we obtain:
$$2(2^k+1)-1 = (2^k \cdot 2 +2)-1 = 2^k \cdot 2 +2-1 = 2\cdot2^k+1$$

Comment: Notice that you can write $3\cdot5$ or $3\times 5$.  Using an asterisk, as in $3*5$, is for occasions when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard. I edited your answer accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: fyi the commands are \cdot and \times (I believe) for the two symbols for multiplication

Answer (score 0):

$$
2\Big( 2^k + 1\Big) - 1 = \Big((2\cdot2^k) +(2\cdot1)\Big) - 1 = (2^{k+1} + 2) - 1 = 2^{k+1}+(2-1) = \cdots
$$